# Using Like Operator in SSRS 2005 IIF Expression

Tags: sql-server-2005, reporting-services

I have a pretty complicated IIF expression in SSRS, in which I want to change the background color of the cell will change based on certain conditions.  It works fine in its current state, but I am trying to add a Like condition to it...

so, here's what it looks like now (working):

```
 =IIf(inscope("matrix1_errorType"), 

IIf(

(
    FormatPercent(Sum(Fields!numberOfIssues.Value)/First(Fields!totalItems.Value),3) >= .0001 & "%" 
    And ( First(Fields!errorType.Value) = "TypeA")
)

Or 
(
    FormatPercent(Sum(Fields!numberOfIssues.Value)/First(Fields!totalItems.Value),3) >= .04 & "%" 
    And First(Fields!errorType.Value) = "TypeB"
)

Or 
(
    FormatPercent(Sum(Fields!numberOfIssues.Value)/First(Fields!totalItems.Value),3) >= .02 & "%" 
    And First(Fields!errorType.Value) = "TypeC"
    )
,
"Maroon", "Transparent")
, "Transparent")
```

What I would like to do is add a Like type statement somewhere in this line, which would say ...and location LIKE "Scan" - in other words, a location with "Scan" somewhere in the title.  locationName is a field i display in the report as well.

```
(
    FormatPercent(Sum(Fields!numberOfIssues.Value)/First(Fields!totalItems.Value),3) >= .0001 & "%" 
    And ( First(Fields!errorType.Value) = "TypeA")
)
```

The like statement would be something similar to:

```
... And ( First(Fields!errorType.Value) = "TypeA") And First(Fields!locationName.Value) Like "*Scan*"
```

but that doesn't work.  I've also tried:

```
And ( First(Fields!errorType.Value) = "TypeA" And First(Fields!locationName.Value.ToString().Contains("Scan")
```

Which doesn't work either.

Any way I can do this in an SSRS 2005 expression?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is syntax.  Double check placements of () and , in your statement as Contains should work for what you are trying.

I also notice your statement:

```
First(Fields!locationName.Value.ToString().Contains("Scan"))
```

Should probably be:

```
First(Fields!locationName.Value).ToString().Contains("Scan")
```

---

You can also try the `IndexOf` function.  IndexOf returns the character position where the string you pass occurs in the source.  So if it's greater than (or equal to) zero your string contains the characters 'Scan' - if less than zero, the source doesn't contain the string.

```
Fields!YourField.Value.ToString().IndexOf("Scan") >= 0
```

Although it works roughly the same as Contains the way your using it.

Comment: Awesome!  And also thanks for explaining IndexOf.  Makes sense now!

Comment: Sweetness!  This just resolved a completely different issue for me wherein I needed to conditionally display a table column based on the value of a client ID. Thanks RThomas.